# Is there any way to save XML data to SQL using XmlDeserialization?

Tags: c#, sql, xml

Can someone post sample code to write XML file data to a SQL database using XmlDeserialization?

I want to save only selected node values to SQL.

This is an example XML node. I want to save every child node value.

```
<Event>
    <ID>ApplicationStart</ID>
    <UserID>
    </UserID>
    <TimeStamp>634577331261524905</TimeStamp>
    <LocationID>5</LocationID>
</Event>
```

**Here is my Code :**

```
StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(path);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<AttendanceLogBo>));
var xmlAttendanceLogBos = serializer.Deserialize(fs) as List<AttendanceLogBo>;  
foreach (var res in xmlAttendanceLogBos.c)
 Console.WriteLine(res.value.OuterXml); 
attendanceLogBos.Add(new AttendanceLogBo()
               {
                   ReaderId = ,
                   CustomEmployeeId = l,
                   LogDateTime = DateTime.Now, //DateTime.Parse((item[2]).Substring(0, 6));
                   EventId = ,
                   EventLogId = 255,
                   IsProcessed = false,
                   LocationId = User.GetCemexUser().LocationId
               });

_logImportService.Uploadlog(attendanceLogBos);
```

I want to add all xml node values to the List

Comment: Can you please update the question with what you have tried so far?